Joint distribution of $XY$ and $X+Y$ when $X$ and $Y$ both follows standard Gaussian
Suppose $X$ and $Y$ follows $N(0,1)$, independently. I want to find the joint distribution of $XY$ and $X+Y$.
I tried to do this using Jacobian transformation. Let $Z_1 = XY$ and $Z_2 = X+Y$ then $Y= Z_1/X$ and $Z_2 = X + Z_1/X$.
Now, the problem is dealing with the second equation, which is a quadratic equation in $X$, that is $ X^2-XZ_2+Z_1=0$. I don't know how to apply the Jacobian here. Any kind of help is appreciated.

To clarify, your trouble is that $(x,y)\mapsto(xy,x+y)$ is not a diffeomorphism? Can you find sets on which it is a diffeomorphism and then proceed? For example, $x\mapsto x^2$ is not a diffeomorphism, but it is if we consider ${x>0}$ and ${x<0}$, from which we can work things out.

@Andrew yes, ultimately you have to separate the problem into two events first, one is ${X>0}$ and another is ${X<0}$.

You just have to go ahead with your strategy. If we solve for $X$ we get
$$
X = \frac{Z_2 \pm \sqrt{Z_2^2 - 4Z_1}}{2}.
$$
The first thing to notice here is that the above expression implies that the joint distribution of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ is only defined in the region where $Z_2^2-4Z_1 > 0$. Regarding the choice of the sign, let us first plug $X$ into the expression for $Y$. We get either the two pairs below:
\begin{align}
X &= \frac{Z_2 + \sqrt{Z_2^2 - 4Z_1}}{2} &\text{and}&& Y &= \frac{Z_2 - \sqrt{Z_2^2 - 4Z_1}}{2} \tag{*}\\
&&\text{or}\\
X &= \frac{Z_2 - \sqrt{Z_2^2 - 4Z_1}}{2} &\text{and}&& Y &= \frac{Z_2 + \sqrt{Z_2^2 - 4Z_1}}{2}.
\end{align}
In other words, we can always swap the values of $X$ and $Y$ and the results won't change.
Before we proceed, let $G$ be a region of the $(Z_1, Z_2)$ plane with $Z_2^2-4Z_1 > 0$. By the Bayesian theorem we have
$$
\Pr[(Z_1,Z_2)\in G] = \Pr\bigl[(Z_1,Z_2)\in G|X\ge Y\bigr]\Pr[X\ge Y] + \Pr\bigl[(Z_1,Z_2)\in G|X < Y\bigr]\Pr[X < Y].
$$
But, because of the symmetry in the problem ($X$ and $Y$ being both standard normal and independent, as well as the interchangeability of $X$ and $Y$ noted above), we have
$$
\Pr[X \ge Y] = \Pr[X < Y] = \frac{1}{2}
$$
and
$$
\Pr\bigl[(Z_1,Z_2)\in G|X\ge Y\bigr] = \Pr\bigl[(Z_1,Z_2)\in G|X< Y\bigr]
$$
which imply
\begin{align}
\Pr\bigl[(Z_1,Z_2)\in G] &= \Pr\bigl[(Z_1,Z_2)\in G|X \ge Y\bigr] \\
&= \Pr\bigl[(Z_1,Z_2)\in G \text{ and }X \ge Y\bigr]/\Pr[X \ge Y\bigr] \\
&= 2\Pr\bigl[(Z_1,Z_2)\in G \text{ and }X \ge Y\bigr]. \tag{**}
\end{align}
Therefore, we consider only the case in (*) and compute the Jacobian:
$$
J = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial X}{\partial Z_1} & \frac{\partial X}{\partial Z_2} \\
\frac{\partial Y}{\partial Z_1} & \frac{\partial Y}{\partial Z_2}
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-1}{\sqrt{Z_2^2 - 4Z_1}} & \frac{1}{2}+\frac{Z_2}{2\sqrt{Z_2^2 - 4Z_1}} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{Z_2^2 - 4Z_1}} & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{Z_2}{2\sqrt{Z_2^2 - 4Z_1}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
whose determinant, in absolute value, is
$$
\lvert \det J \rvert = \frac{1}{\sqrt{Z_2^2 - 4Z_1}}.
$$
Finally, let $p(x)$ be the pdf of the standard normal distribution.
From (**) we can compute the joint distribution of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ as
\begin{align}
f_{Z_1,Z_2}(z_1,z_2) &= 2 p\left(\frac{z_2 + \sqrt{z_2^2 - 4z_1}}{2}\right)p\left(\frac{z_2 - \sqrt{z_2^2 - 4z_1}}{2}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{z_2^2 - 4z_1}}\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{z_2 + \sqrt{z_2^2 - 4z_1}}{2}\right)^2\right) \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{z_2 - \sqrt{z_2^2 + 4z_1}}{2}\right)^2\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{z_2^2 - 4z_1}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{z_2^2 - 4z_1}} \exp\Bigr(-\frac{1}{2} \bigl(z_2^2 - 2z_1\bigr)\Bigr)
\end{align}
which, we recall, is defined for all $(z_1, z_2)$ such that $z_2^2 - 4z_1 > 0$.

Sorry, just realized that I had forgotten a factor 2 in the last step. I took the opportunity to provide some more details.
